how do i resolve this 'error running pod install'?
Every time I launch the application, I receive this message. I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall cocoapods, but it does not work.
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for
nil:NilClass
      report.issues = results['items'].map { |item| Issue.new(item) }

uninstall and reinstall cocoapods anyway find on youtube

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
